# Problem with columns when importing file with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a problem when importing text files on Pandas. There is no problem with columns when I open the file in the text, but when I open it with Pandas, I can't split the columns and Jupiter-notebook recognizes it as one column. I want to have three columns with the title 'Z 'H' and 'err'.[what will give me when I open the saved file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jN1kQ.png)

```
data= np.genfromtxt('/path/hubel.dat')
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns= ['Z', 'H', 'err']
df_groupby_err=df.groupby("err")
for err, H  in df.groupby("err"):
    if err<20:
        print( )
        print( H )
        print( ) 
f=open("hubble_error_edited-2.txt", "w")
for err, H in df.groupby("err"):
    if err<20:
        f.write("\n"+str(H)+""+ "\n")
f.close()
data= pd.read_csv("/path/hubble_error_edited-2.txt" )
```

Comment: If I'm understanding your program, you read data into a dataframe, then groupby and write out the string representation of each group (space delimited) then attempt to use `read_csv` when you do not have comma separated values.

Comment: Your [mre] should always include a minimal example of the data.  Why did you choose numpy.genfromtxt instead of one of the [Pandas I/O tools](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/io.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add a `blank space` in the `separator` parameter :

```py
data= pd.read_csv("/path/hubble_error_edited-2.txt", sep=' ')
```